# Multiprocessing with Queue(): TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

This is my code:

```
def search(page, sort, start, end, q):
    print(mp.current_process())
    results = req.request_buff_market_page(page, sort, start, end)

    for i in results:
        if(i[1] >= 20 and 'Souvenir' not in i[0]):
            q.put(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 1
    q = queue.Queue()
    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        print(page)
        pool.starmap(search, (page, 'asc', 200, 205, q))
        page += 1

    while not(q.empty()):
        print(q.get())
```

Output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ultralight\mp_buff.py", line 33, in <module>
        pool.starmap(search, (page, 'asc', 200, 205, q))
    .........
    TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. The error occurs on this line:

> pool.starmap(search, (page, 'asc', 200, 205, q))

**EDIT: Changed my code to use multiprocessing.Process()**

```
 for i in range(mp.cpu_count()):
     workers.append(mp.Process(target=search, args=(page, 'asc', 200, 230, q_search)))
     page += 1
 for i in workers: i.start()
 for i in workers: i.join()
```

Comment: You can't use a `queue.Queue` with `multiprocessing`. Use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead.

Comment: @dano Thanks, I realized that a while after posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating your multiprocessing pool as a multithreading pool, which is not the same thing. Look into `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: I changed my code to use `workers.append(mp.Process(target=search, args=(page, 'asc', 200, 205, q)))` instead of a Pool, and it worked. So do you know if it is better to use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` or `Process()`?

Comment: The better option depends on what you're doing in your worker function. If you are doing CPU-bound work that does not release the GIL, using threads will not improve performance; you'll have to use sub-processes.

Comment: @Andrew Though passing the `Queue` directly to `mp.Process` may not throw an error, the queue is not actually usable between processes, you have to use `mp.Queue` for that.